# Focus CSS tag in Internet Explorer 8

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8

This is driving me nuts.

http://www.cssdrive.com/index.php/examples/exampleitem/focus_pseudo_class

This is an example of using the hover pseudo-class. Works fine in Chrome and IE. When I save locally it works fine in Chrome but won't work in IE. What am I doing wrong!?

```
<link rel="Stylesheet" href="style.css" />
<form>
    <p>1) Name:<br />
    <input type="text" size="40"></p>

    <p>2) Email address:<br />
    <input type="text" size="40"></p>

    <p>3) Comments:<br />
    <textarea rows="5" name="comments" cols="45" wrap="virtual"></textarea></p>

    <p><input id="actualsubmit" type="submit" value="Submit"></p>
</form>
```

style.css:

```
input:focus, textarea:focus{
    background-color: lightyellow;
}
```

EDIT:
The style sheet is applying - can be tested by background-color: black. But the focus effect is not working.

Comment: Have you tried putting that `<link>` in the `<head>`?

Comment: Sure have tried it in <head>, this was just copy/pasted from the example, but the style is being applied as setting body { background-color: black } applies.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe that IE8 still doesn't support it properly, here's a JS workaround:
http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/fixing-focus-in-internet-explorer/

Answer (score 2):

It appears as though IE8 fails when the style is `<link>`'d rather than `<style>`'d on the page.

Answer (score -1):

Try "stylesheet" instead of "Stylesheet" in your link tag? Might be case-sensitive.