# Dropdown list is narrow in IE8, and opens upwards

Tags: jquery, asp.net, html, css, internet-explorer-8

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Select dropdown with fixed width cutting off content in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/682764/select-dropdown-with-fixed-width-cutting-off-content-in-ie)

In chrome and even IE 9 the drop list displays fine, the width of the drop down list doesn't cut any of the text off, and when you open the drop down, the options are displayed normally i.e. it opens up with the options below or towards the bottom of the browser.

In IE8, for some reason the drop down list is very narrow, and the list opens upwards so to speak, i.e. the options are touching the top of the browser window.

How can I fix this?

Comment: post the code creating the problem

Comment: Seems to be a well known problem check out this post for fixes for this issue 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10111882/controlling-the-drop-down-list-width-in-ie8-on-select

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to fix the cutting of the text by setting the width of the dropdown explicitly. Or you can apply a `CssClass`.

The DropDown opens on the direction on which it has the more real state available to display most of the items in the list. If you scroll to the top of the page and click on the dropdown, it will display towards the bottom provided it has more room on this direction than towards the top. With that said, [there's nothing you can do about this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/570642/height-of-an-html-select-box-dropdown/570651#570651) There's no way to control the height of the scrollable area in the dropdown list.

Comment: yes I was guessing that was the issue, but IE9 and chrome/firefox don't have this problem so maybe their algorithm for figuring that value out is really nuts!?